# Nginx 301 domain redirect not working

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, 301-redirect

I am trying to redirect (or I guess forward) my old domain (`example.com`) to my new domain (`example2.com`) now that I have updated my server config to accommodate the new domain. However, it doesn't appear that the 301 redirect clause in my Nginx config is working properly because I'm still able to access `example.com`, which redirects to `https://www.example.com` like the configuration that was set up prior to pointing this server to the new domain. When `https://www.example.com` is accessed it renders `Your connection is not private` which makes sense as I changed the SSL config to point to the certificates for `example2.com`. Is there something wrong with my 301 configuration? If there isn't, could it be that I still have an `A record (example.com)` and `CNAME record (www.example.com)` pointing to my IP address that is allow access to the site through the old domain to exist?

*Note:* I have no problem accessing `example2.com` which redirect to `https://www.example2.com` as expected

**Here is my Nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example2.com www.example2.com example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-www.example2.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    server_name example2.com;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-www.example2.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name www.example2.com;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location ~ ^/\.well-known {
        root /var/www/ghost;
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Referer "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache? Also, there's no point forwarding domains where you've given up the A/CNAME record.

Comment: It's not this config that's redirecting example.com to https://www.example.com.

Comment: @RichardSmith I cleared my cache, but I still run into the issue mentioned in the question and have not deleted A/CNAME records yet

Comment: @GerardH.Pille can you elaborate? I'm not sure I follow

Comment: I can't elaborate.  The config you've added to your question, would not redirect  example.com to H T T P S : / / w w w . example.com.  (in my previous comment, you need to put the cursor above the link).

Comment: Where is your configuration for the old domain?

Comment: Did your old domain specify an HSTS header? You may need to reset the browser to destroy that association.

Comment: @RichardSmith so I think it might have needed a browser rest to destroy the association. If I navigate to `example.com` then it redirects to `https://www.example2.com`, but if I navigate to `https://www.example.com` it doesn't redirect and tries to access a server at that location (`www.example.com`) with the `unsafe connection` warning. Any thoughts?

Comment: By `unsafe connection` I meant `Your connection is not private`. `This server could not prove it is www.example.com; its security certificate is from example2.com`

Comment: As has previously been stated: you do not have a redirection set up for `https://example.com` - it will be handled by the third `server` block (the default server for port 443). Move the `default_server` from the third block to the second block. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for more. All this is probably pointless if you do not have a certificate for the old domain.

Comment: @RichardSmith I still have the certificate for the old domain and now I understand what you are saying. For some reason I interpreted the `http` port block to be a a global redirect when in reality it only will redirect when someone accesses the previous website with `http`. Based on your suggestion, should I remove the top to `server_name www.example2.com;` in the third block and append `default_server` to the end of the two `listen` lines in the second server block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have to set IPv6 unless you want to use it specifically. Use your config like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example2.com www.example2.com example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example2.com;
    return 301 https://www.example2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example2.com;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/example2.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example2.com.key;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location ~ ^/\.well-known {
        root /var/www/ghost;
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Referer "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

Also, do not forget to create the /etc/nginx/ssl folder and the dhparam.pem file.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl && sudo openssl dhparam -dsaparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 4096
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you briefly summarize the changes you propose and how my config was wrong? This will make it easier to understand why I should follow your answer.

Comment: I believe I am following along now. I used Let's Encrypt so the ssl server block you have set up is already referenced in files in another directory. As a result should I just reference those paths in my server block? For instance `/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem` is the path for `ssl_dhparam` and `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf` contains `ssl_protocols`, `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers`, and `ssl_ciphers`

Comment: What I've modified is: removed IPv6 | removed those includes from server blocks | added a proper ssl key setting for the last server block | enhanced your SSL config with the dhparam, protocol, chipers etc.... Also, the `allow all` can be removed as well, unless you want to deny some specific addresses.